# Qt C++ убрать кнопки и рамку окна с MessageBox

Tags: c++, qt, messagebox

Есть ли возможность убрать рамку с `MessageBox` по типу диалогового окна? флаги `popup tool tooltip` и тд работать не хотят. И как убрать стандартную кнопку?  хочу убрать их все, оставим только текст и фон окна. флаг `Qt:NoButton` оставляет кнопку Ок по умолчанию.

Answer (score 1):

Можно вот так изоброзить

```
QMessageBox* pmbx =
                    new QMessageBox("MessageBox",
                    "<b>A</b> <i>Simple</i>   <u>Message</u>",
                    QMessageBox::Information,
                    QMessageBox::Cancel | QMessageBox::Escape);
int n = pmbx->exec(); 
delete pmbx;
```

Comment: а вообще напиши свой диалог для сообщений и вызывай его)

Comment: exec() не покатит, мне не требуется кнопку нажимать и в дальнейшим обрабатывать ее нажатие. Рамки как понял нельзя убрать. Да видимо что бы было красиво, придётся писать свой диалог.